# Can assets be protected from sale in bankruptcy by a contract not to sell them?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, bankruptcy

It is apparently common to not be allowed to resell seeds obtained from growing genetically modified plants, as a condition of having the original seeds sold to you. But one might have several thousand dollars worth of such seeds as a business asset, which, if not for the prohibition on resale, could be sold to satisfy creditors.

**Do contractual agreements not to sell things survive bankruptcy and prevent those things from being sold off to pay creditors?** Or would the things be seized away from the legal person who is bound by the ontract, and only then sold off, free of the contractual encumbrance, by a different entity?

(It might be that in this particular example it is *really* the lack of a patent license, rather than the presence of a contract term, that prevents the sale. Please ignore that. I am interested in whether *contractual terms* can prevent asset sales.)